# Trying to pivot a table with dynamic column

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have data like so returned from a hosted service.

> [{ media: instagram, affiliate: george, date: 02/01/2019, spend: 20.00, cart_assists: 2, sales: 3},
>
> { media: instagram, affiliate: tina, date: 02/01/2019, spend: 10.00, cart_assists: 1, sales: 0},
>
> { media: instagram, affiliate: george, date: 02/02/2019, spend: 30.00, cart_assists: 12, sales: 4},
>
> { media: instagram, affiliate: tina, date: 02/02/2019, spend: 40.00, cart_assists: 0, sales: 1}]

I am trying to pivot the data using google apps script, I added the javascript tag since any javascript solution could be used in google apps script.

I would like the data to look as follows and I am having trouble coming up with a solution.

```html
<table>
<th>media</th>
<th>affiliate</th>
<th>spend: 02/01/2019</th>
<th>spend: 02/02/2019</th>
<th>cart_assists: 02/01/2019</th>
<th>cart_assists: 02/02/2019</th>
<th>sales: 02/01/2019</th>
<th>sales: 02/02/2019</th>
</table>
```

Comment: Where are you trying to do this? In an HTMLService? Is the data coming in server-side or client-side? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Also: the mapping you are aiming for is not clear. How does `cart_assists: 12` turn into `cart_assists: 02/01/2019`, and so on? Are you discarding the values for `media` & `affiliate` values?

Comment: The data is coming server side using sql server.  Currently I am trying to pivot a table I have created.

SELECT * FROM 
(select 
 convert(date,cal_date) as date,
 scn as scn, 
 sca as sca,
 media_source_id,
 is_rolled_up,
 isnull(sum(spend),0) as spend
 --ISNULL(sum(sale_assists),0) as sale_assists,
 --ISNULL(sum(cart_assists),0) as cart_assists
from @totals
group by 
 cal_date,
 scn,
 sca,
 media_source_id,
 is_rolled_up ) AS test
PIVOT (MAX(spend) FOR date IN ([02/01/2019], [02/02/2019])) AS test1